# UWP ListView Item context menu

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, contextmenu

I'm searching internet for how to add context menu for `ListView`. So far I've found one that actually displays context

```
<ListView>
    ...
    RightTapped="ContactsListView_RightTapped" >
    ...
    <ListView.Resources>
        <MenuFlyout x:Name="allContactsMenuFlyout">
            <MenuFlyout.Items>
                <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="Edit"  Text="Edit"/>
                <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="Remove" Text="Remove"    Click="Remove_Click"/>
            </MenuFlyout.Items>
        </MenuFlyout>
    </ListView.Resources>
    ...
</ListView>

private void ContactsListView_RightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e) {
    ListView listView = (ListView)sender;
    allContactsMenuFlyout.ShowAt(listView, e.GetPosition(listView));
}

private void Remove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

}
```

The problem is I'm not able to get item on which the context menu was displayed. Another issue is that the context menu is displayed also outside of list view item (e.g. on borders). And since the event that is triggered is RightTapped, I'm not sure if the context menu would be displayed on long click on mobile devices. I cannot test it because my emulators are not currently working. Since it should be universal windows app I was expecting some really easy and efficient way of creating context menus for ListView items.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> The problem is I'm not able to get item on which the context menu was displayed.

For this problem, if you add data to the `ListView` like this:

```
<ListView RightTapped="ListView_RightTapped">
    <x:String>First Item</x:String>
    <x:String>Second Item</x:String>
    <x:String>Third Item</x:String>
    <x:String>Fourth Item</x:String>

    <ListView.Resources>
        <MenuFlyout x:Name="allContactsMenuFlyout">
            <MenuFlyout.Items>
                <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="Edit"  Text="Edit" />
                <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="Remove" Text="Remove"    Click="Remove_Click" />
            </MenuFlyout.Items>
        </MenuFlyout>
    </ListView.Resources>
</ListView>
```

You can get the item's context in the `RightTapped` event like this:

```cs
private void ListView_RightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ListView listView = (ListView)sender;
    allContactsMenuFlyout.ShowAt(listView, e.GetPosition(listView));
    var a = ((FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource).DataContext;
}
```

In this scenario, "a" will directly get the string format content of clicked item.

If you add your data to `ListView` using `DataTemplate` like this:

```
<ListView RightTapped="ListView_RightTapped" ItemsSource="{x:Bind list}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding text}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.Resources>
        <MenuFlyout x:Name="allContactsMenuFlyout">
            <MenuFlyout.Items>
                <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="Edit"  Text="Edit" />
                <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="Remove" Text="Remove"    Click="Remove_Click" />
            </MenuFlyout.Items>
        </MenuFlyout>
    </ListView.Resources>
</ListView>
```

and usually when using `DataTemplate`, we add data by `ObservableCollection` like this:

```cs
private ObservableCollection<List> list = new ObservableCollection<List>();

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    list.Clear();
    list.Add(new List { text = "Item 1" });
    list.Add(new List { text = "Item 2" });
    list.Add(new List { text = "Item 3" });
    list.Add(new List { text = "Item 4" });
    list.Add(new List { text = "Item 5" });
}
```

"List" class is quite simple here for test:

```cs
public class List
{
    public string text { get; set; }
}
```

Then also we can get the `DataContext` in the `RightTapped` event:

```cs
private void ListView_RightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ListView listView = (ListView)sender;
    allContactsMenuFlyout.ShowAt(listView, e.GetPosition(listView));
    var a = ((FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource).DataContext;
}
```

But this time, "a" is actually the 'List' object (please refer to the "List" class) inside the item, because the content of the item is now a 'List' object, not a string any more. So we can get the text property of this object like this:

```cs
private void ListView_RightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ListView listView = (ListView)sender;
    allContactsMenuFlyout.ShowAt(listView, e.GetPosition(listView));
    var a = ((FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource).DataContext as List;
    var content = a.text;
}
```

I think eventually you want to edit the content in the Button click event of the `Flyout`, you can do it for example like this:

```cs
private string content;

private void ListView_RightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ListView listView = (ListView)sender;
    allContactsMenuFlyout.ShowAt(listView, e.GetPosition(listView));
    var a = ((FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource).DataContext as List;
    content = a.text;
}

private void Remove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in list.ToList())
    {
        if (item.text == content)
        {
            list.Remove(item);
        }
    }
    content = "";
}
```

> Another issue is that the context menu is displayed also outside of list view item (e.g. on borders).

Can you explain this? I can't quite understand it. You mean displaying the content for example in the `Flyout`? If so, I think the method above can solve this problem. If not, you can leave a comment, and I will see if this problem can be resolved.

> And since the event that is triggered is RightTapped, I'm not sure if the context menu would be displayed on long click on mobile devices.

I think that "long click" event here indicates the `Holding` event like this?

```cs
private void ListView_Holding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ListView listView = (ListView)sender;
    allContactsMenuFlyout.ShowAt(listView, e.GetPosition(listView));
    var a = ((FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource).DataContext as List;
    content = a.text;
}
```

I just test it on the Mobile Emulator, it works fine. Although I wrote a quite long answer here, but the key point is quite simple, you can just use `((FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource).DataContext` to get the Context of the item.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Command` instead of `Click` event. You can pass the clicked item in `CommandParameter`

```xml
<MenuFlyout x:Name="allContactsMenuFlyout">
                <MenuFlyout.Items>
                    <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="Edit"  Text="Edit"/>
                    <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="Remove" Text="Remove" Command="{Binding Path=DeleteItemTappedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ArchivedMessages_ListView, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
                </MenuFlyout.Items>
   </MenuFlyout>
```

Inside your ViewModel

```cs
public DelegateCommand<object> DeleteItemTappedCommand { get; set; }

 public YourViewModel()
 {
     DeleteItemTappedCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(DeleteItemClicked);
 }

 private void DeleteItemClicked(object obj)
 {
     // adjust object type to your templated source type
 }
```

or for the `CommunityToolkit.MVVM` users:

```cs
[ICommand]
private void DeleteItemClicked(object obj)
{
    // adjust object type to your templated source type
}
```

Comment: THX for response. I'm gonna try it. But the event that triggers this is still right click on list view. So it'll be triggered e. g. when I right click on header of a group in list view, or on a border. I was expecting something really easy to implement, since this is common functionality.

Comment: Binding makes sense but it is always `null`.  Have not had any success getting the `Command` property to attach to anything.

Comment: Try using `Behaviors` and `InvokeCommandAction` from prism framework

Answer (score 1):

Add flyout in the datatemplate. Use command to deal with the events.
See sample code here:

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="ListItemTemplate" >
    <Grid  x:Name="gridItem"  RightTapped="gridItem_RightTapped">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Name="imgProduct" Width="50" Height="50" Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding ProductUrl}" Margin="0,5,10,5" VerticalAlignment="Center" ></Image>
        <TextBlock Name="tbName" Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  ></TextBlock>
        <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
            <MenuFlyout>
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Delete" Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteCommand, ElementName=contentGrid}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"  />
            </MenuFlyout>
        </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Code behind:

```
private void gridItem_RightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout(sender as FrameworkElement);
}
```

You can get the full solution here: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-implement-flyout-ef52517f