# Swipe Buttons On Listview Row

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, swipe

I am currently setting up a new xamarin app which will target UWP / Android and one of the things I need to do is to swipe a row on a list view to show an action button (which will more than likely be an edit / delete button depending on the side of swiping). I have had a look at GestureRecognizers which I have not got to work - this was quite possibly because I was trying to put this on a label control, however, after a couple of days of trying to locate a best practice way of doing this I'm coming up against a brick wall. Suggestions and ideally github repos at this stage to demonstrate a working solution would be really useful.

I have gone around google looking for a solution, I have a subscription with DevExpress and used their grid when I had an Android only app. This worked absolutely brilliantly - however, their xamarin.forms control does not work with UWP.

The expected result is to look the same as a DevExpress grid view: https://documentation.devexpress.com/HelpResource.ashx?help=Xamarin&document=img18128.jpg

Thanks

Chris

Comment: Here is a discussion about UWP using `Context Menu`,you can  refer to.(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36741757/uwp-listview-item-context-menu)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've had a look into this and the flyout doesn't seem to be workable with existing code base (I've tried to integrate with little success). However, I've now seen that SyncFusion offer a community licence which means I can use this as it offers the functionality I require although it would be good to be able to use this functionality in my own control in time.