# UWP Combobox SelectedItem from GridView Control and also Bind selection change value to model with MVVM Pattern

Tags: c#, windows, mvvm, uwp, windows-10

i am trying to

1. Select Combobox Item when user select on datagrid row
2. when user add new user then item selected by user from combobox 
   in my view model and what i have tried is follow :
   **View:**

```
        <Button Content="Update" Grid.Row="12" Height="35" Grid.Column="0" Margin="90,15,0,0" Name="btnUpdate"   
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141"  
                Command="{Binding Path=UpdateCommand}" 
                CommandParameter="{Binding Path=_Userdetails}"
                >

        </Button>
        <controls:DataGrid x:Name="dgvEmpList" Margin="0,0,480,457"
                           Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="12" Grid.Column="1" GridLinesVisibility="All"
                           AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue"
                           HeadersVisibility="Column"
                           ItemsSource="{Binding Users, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"   
                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                           AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                          >
            <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn 
            Header="UserId"            
            Binding="{Binding UserId}" 
             />
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn 
            Header="FirstName"            
            Binding="{Binding FirstName}" 
             />
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn 
            Header="LastName"            
            Binding="{Binding LastName}" 
             />

                <controls:DataGridTextColumn 
            Header="City"

            Binding="{Binding City}" />
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn 
            Header="State"

            Binding="{Binding State}" />
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn 
            Header="Country"

            Binding="{Binding Country}" />




            </controls:DataGrid.Columns>

        </controls:DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

**My text box and Combobox are in view like :**

```
<TextBlock x:Name="label2" Padding="18,0,0,0" Margin="10,20,0,0" Text="First Name :"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="19" Width="86"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtFName" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding _Userdetails.FirstName,Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedText="{Binding SelectedUser.FirstName}" AcceptsReturn="True"   PlaceholderText="Enter FirstName ..." Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Width="292" TextAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="28,0,0,0" Height="32"></TextBox>
 <ComboBox x:Name="cmbCountry" PlaceholderText="Select Country ..." Text="{Binding _Userdetails.Country,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="11" Grid.Column="0" Width="292"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="28,0,0,0" Height="32">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="India"></ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Canada"></ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="USA"></ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="ENGLAND"></ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="New Zealand"></ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
```

**Model :**

```
 public class User : BindableBase
    {
        private int userId;
        private string firstName;
        private string lastName;
        private string city;
        private string state;
        private string country;
        public int UserId
        {
            get
            {
                return userId;
            }
            set
            {
                userId = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("UserId");
            }
        }
        public string FirstName
        {
            get
            {
                return firstName;
            }
            set
            {
                firstName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
            }
        }
        public string LastName
        {
            get
            {
                return lastName;
            }
            set
            {
                lastName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("LastName");
            }
        }
        public string City
        {
            get
            {
                return city;
            }
            set
            {
                city = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("City");
            }
        }
        public string State
        {
            get
            {
                return state;
            }
            set
            {
                state = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("State");
            }
        }
        public string Country
        {
            get
            {
                return country;
            }
            set
            {
                country = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Country");
            }
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members  

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        #endregion

    }
```

**View Model :**

```
public class UserViewModel : User,INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private ObservableCollection<User> _UsersList { get; set; }
        private User selecteduser;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public User _Userdetails { get; set; }
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)//string propertyName
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)

            {
                PropertyChangedEventArgs args = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
                this.PropertyChanged(this, args);
            }
        }

        public UserViewModel()
        {
            _UsersList = new ObservableCollection<User>
            {
                new User{UserId = 1,FirstName="Raj",LastName="Beniwal",City="Delhi",State="DEL",Country="INDIA"},
                new User{UserId=2,FirstName="Mark",LastName="henry",City="New York", State="NY", Country="USA"},
                new User{UserId=3,FirstName="Mahesh",LastName="Chand",City="Philadelphia", State="PHL", Country="USA"},
                new User{UserId=4,FirstName="Vikash",LastName="Nanda",City="Noida", State="UP", Country="CANADA"},
                new User{UserId=5,FirstName="Harsh",LastName="Kumar",City="Ghaziabad", State="UP", Country="INDIA"},
                new User{UserId=6,FirstName="Reetesh",LastName="Tomar",City="Mumbai", State="MP", Country="INDIA"},
                new User{UserId=7,FirstName="Deven",LastName="Verma",City="Palwal", State="HP", Country="ENGLAND"},
                new User{UserId=8,FirstName="Ravi",LastName="Taneja",City="Delhi", State="DEL", Country="INDIA"}
            };
            try
            {
                _Userdetails = new User();

            }
            catch 
            {
            }
            UpdateCommand = new RelayCommand(AddUserMethod);


        }
        public RelayCommand UpdateCommand { get; set; }


        public void AddUserMethod(object parameter)
        {
            try
            {
                _UsersList.Add(
                new User
                {

                    FirstName = _Userdetails.FirstName,
                    LastName = _Userdetails.LastName,
                    City = _Userdetails.City,
                    Country = _Userdetails.Country,
                    State = _Userdetails.State,
                    UserId = _Userdetails.UserId

                });
            }
            catch
            {

            }




        }
        public User userdetails
        {
            get
            {
                return _Userdetails;
            }
            set
            {
                _Userdetails = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("userdetails");
            }
        }

        public User SelectedUser
        {
            get
            {
                return selecteduser;
            }
            set
            {
                selecteduser = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedUser");
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<User> Users
        {
            get
            { return _UsersList; }
            set
            {
                _UsersList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Users");
            }
        }


    }
```

i have done this for textbox controls which works fine but for combobox i can't find what i want to do so please help me

Comment: So, your requirement is select  item for both at same time, right?

Comment: no once user select grid view row then combobox item must be selected and when user tries to save new user then selected item will be available in viewmodel country property

Comment: in textbox i get text in view model with Text="{Binding _Userdetails.State,Mode=TwoWay}" and show datagridview value in text box like SelectedText="{Binding SelectedUser.State}"

Comment: but when try to do same in combobox and it doesnot work my combobox doesn't have any itemsource itjust have static items list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but when try to do same in combobox and it doesnot work my combobox doesn't have any itemsource itjust have static items list.

The problem is you have bind wrong property (Text Property ) for `ComboBox`. For your scenario, you need to make a country list for `ComboBox` and bind `SelectedItem` property. I have re-write your code. please check the following.

**User.cs**

```
public class User : ViewModelBase
{
    private int userId;
    private string firstName;
    private string lastName;
    private string city;
    private string state;
    private string country;
    public int UserId
    {
        get
        {
            return userId;
        }
        set
        {
            userId = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("UserId");
        }
    }
    public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return firstName;
        }
        set
        {
            firstName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
        }
    }
    public string LastName
    {
        get
        {
            return lastName;
        }
        set
        {
            lastName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("LastName");
        }
    }
    public string City
    {
        get
        {
            return city;
        }
        set
        {
            city = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("City");
        }
    }
    public string State
    {
        get
        {
            return state;
        }
        set
        {
            state = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("State");
        }
    }
    public string Country
    {
        get
        {
            return country;
        }
        set
        {
            country = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Country");
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members  

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion

}
```

**UserModel.cs**

```
public class UserViewModel : User, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private ObservableCollection<User> _usersList;
    private User _userdetails;
    private User _selecteduser;
    private string _countrySelectItem;
    public ObservableCollection<string> CountryList { get; set; }
    public User Userdetails
    {
        get
        {
            return _userdetails;
        }
        set
        {
            _userdetails = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Userdetails");
        }
    }

    public string CountrySelectItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _countrySelectItem;
        }
        set
        {
            _countrySelectItem = value;
            _userdetails.Country = _countrySelectItem;
            OnPropertyChanged("CountrySelectItem");
        }
    }

    public User SelectedUser
    {
        get
        {
            return _selecteduser;
        }
        set
        {
            _selecteduser = value;

           if( CountryList.Any(p => p == _selecteduser.Country))
            {
                CountrySelectItem = _selecteduser.Country;
            }else
            {
                CountrySelectItem = null;
            }

            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedUser");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<User> Users
    {
        get
        { return _usersList; }
        set
        {
            _usersList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Users");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)//string propertyName
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)

        {
            PropertyChangedEventArgs args = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            this.PropertyChanged(this, args);
        }
    }

    public UserViewModel()
    {
        _usersList = new ObservableCollection<User>
        {
            new User{UserId=1,FirstName="Raj",LastName="Beniwal",City="Delhi",State="DEL",Country="INDIA"},
            new User{UserId=2,FirstName="Mark",LastName="henry",City="New York", State="NY", Country="USA"},
            new User{UserId=3,FirstName="Mahesh",LastName="Chand",City="Philadelphia", State="PHL", Country="USA"},
            new User{UserId=4,FirstName="Vikash",LastName="Nanda",City="Noida", State="UP", Country="CANADA"},
            new User{UserId=5,FirstName="Harsh",LastName="Kumar",City="Ghaziabad", State="UP", Country="INDIA"},
            new User{UserId=6,FirstName="Reetesh",LastName="Tomar",City="Mumbai", State="MP", Country="INDIA"},
            new User{UserId=7,FirstName="Deven",LastName="Verma",City="Palwal", State="HP", Country="ENGLAND"},
            new User{UserId=8,FirstName="Ravi",LastName="Taneja",City="Delhi", State="DEL", Country="INDIA"},
             new User{UserId=9,FirstName="Nico",LastName="Ming",City="WuXi", State="DEL", Country="China"}
        };
        CountryList = new ObservableCollection<string>()
        {
            "INDIA",
            "CANADA",
            "USA",
            "ENGLAND",
            "New Zealand"
        };

        try
        {
            _userdetails = new User();

        }
        catch
        {
        }

        UpdateCommand = new RelayCommand<User>(AddUserMethod);
    }
    public RelayCommand<User> UpdateCommand { get; set; }

    public void AddUserMethod(User parameter)
    {
        try
        {
            _usersList.Add(
            new User
            {

                FirstName = _userdetails.FirstName,
                LastName = _userdetails.LastName,
                City = _userdetails.City,
                Country = _userdetails.Country,
                State = _userdetails.State,
                UserId = _userdetails.UserId

            });
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**Xaml code**

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:UserViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
</Page.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="6*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button
        Name="btnUpdate"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Width="141"
        Height="35"
        Margin="90,15,0,0"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Command="{Binding Path=UpdateCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Userdetails}"
        Content="Update"
        />

    <controls:DataGrid
        x:Name="dgvEmpList"
        Grid.Row="1"
        AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        GridLinesVisibility="All"
        HeadersVisibility="Column"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Users, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        >
        <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
            <controls:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding UserId}" Header="UserId" />
            <controls:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FirstName}" Header="FirstName" />
            <controls:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding LastName}" Header="LastName" />
            <controls:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding City}" Header="City" />
            <controls:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding State}" Header="State" />
            <controls:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Country}" Header="Country" />
        </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
    </controls:DataGrid>

    <TextBox
        x:Name="txtFName"
        Grid.Row="2"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        Width="292"
        Height="32"
        Margin="28,0,0,0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        AcceptsReturn="True"
        PlaceholderText="Enter FirstName ..."
        SelectedText="{Binding SelectedUser.FirstName}"
        Text="{Binding Userdetails.FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}"
        TextAlignment="Left"
        TextWrapping="Wrap"
        />
    <ComboBox
        x:Name="cmbCountry"
        Grid.Row="4"
        Width="292"
        Height="32"
        Margin="28,0,0,0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        ItemsSource="{Binding CountryList}"
        PlaceholderText="Select Country ..."
        SelectedItem="{Binding CountrySelectItem,Mode=TwoWay}"   
        >

        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

And this is complete [code project](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/ComboboxAndDataGridTest) that you could refer.

Comment: is it possible to open menuflyout on datagrid from viewmodel ?

Comment: Yep, it could add menuflyout, may you could refer this case [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36760522/7254781).

Comment: that code is code behind i don't want to write code behind event

Comment: You could bind tap or click event with method in code behind. please check [this](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/ComboboxAndDataGridTest/blob/master/ComboboxAndDataGridTest/MainPage.xaml#L31).

Comment: i successfully added event to viewmodel but how can pass menu to that event

Comment: please check this [line](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/SoCaseStatusCheckTool/blob/master/SoCaseStatusCheckTool/SoCaseStatusCheckTool/ViewModels/MainPageViewModel.cs#L133).